# how to make force css print on chrome

Tags: html, css, printing

I need to make a force print on google chrome print option
i try to use this code on CSS and its force make portrait or landscape
but i need to make force to page size like A5 or A6

```css
@media print{
 @page {
  size: portrait;
  margin-top: 0cm;
        margin-bottom: 0cm;
        margin-left: 0cm;
        margin-right: 0cm;
 }
}
```

is it code for force option to select A5 or A6 option on print option like portrait or landscope

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. Just setting `size: A4 landscape;`

```
@media print {
 @page {
    size: A4 landscape;
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%
    }
}
```

Depending on your img or whatever your trying to print you can also set your img under @page to make it fit better.

```
img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    }
```

Comment: not working, i think its need to make code for force page size

Comment: You can try 
`@media print {
   html,body {
      height:100%;
      width:100%;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
}
 @page {
    size: A4 landscape;
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%
    }
}`